# Is the intersection of a nested sequence of compact subsets of a metric space equal to the smallest subset?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Cantor's intersection theorem states

> Let $S$ be a topological space. Given a decreasing nested sequence of bounded nonempty compact, closed subsets of S satisfying
>   $$C_1 \supset C_2 \supset C_3 \supset ...$$
>   it follows that
>   $$ \left(\bigcap _{k}C_{k}\right)\neq \emptyset$$

Wouldn't the intersection of all $C_k$ simply just be the subset $C_N$ with the largest index?

Comment: What if there are infinitely many such intervals, though? What exactly is the "largest" index?

Comment: @Gae.S. yes, of course. I corrected my comment.

Comment: @Gae.S. yes, you are right again.

Comment: It does not make sense, as far as I know, to classify a subset of a topological space as "bounded" or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that for finite $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\cap_{k=1}^{N} C_{k} = C_{N}$. But consider $C_{n} = \left[ -\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} \right] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Taking an infinite intersection, we have that $\cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} C_{k} = \{ 0 \}$. Here, the notion of largest index does not quite make sense. In a general topological space, $\cap_{k} C_{k}$ is non-empty because one can construct a sequence which converges in the intersection by the closed property of the intersection.

Comment: Or consider the Cantor set, where every $C_n$ is a finite union of intervals and the intersection contains no interval at all...

Comment: Or the intersection is nonempty because it is a family of closed subsets of a compact set, and every finite subfamily has nonempty intersection; hence the entire family has nonempty intersection.